# RingtonePreference not saving selected value

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a preferences activity that includes preference fragments for different categories of settings. One of the preference fragments includes a RingtonePreference and the problem I have is that the value that is selected is not saved. I have read similar posts about the same issue but they did not help. The intent for launching the main preferences activity has the following flags:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

I have tried removing all flags except FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK but it did not help. The manifest declaration for the activity does not include any flags.

I have also tried overriding the onPreferenceChanged listener for the RingtonePreference but is is also not called. The problem, as I have read from other posts must be in the OnActivityResult of the preference (not being called) but I cannot understand why.

Can anyone help?